# How can I make a NavigationTitle in SwiftUI open a picker view?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I understand that you can bind a string to the navigation title like:

`.navigationTitle($titleString)`

and you get:

[image]

and this will allow you to rename it,
but is there a way to bind this to an enum to get a picker view?

(this doesn't work btw) :

```
enum LibraryViewType: String, CaseIterable {
    case albums, songs, artists
}

...

@State private var viewType: LibraryViewType = .albums

...

.navigationTitle($viewType)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where you should use [`ToolbarTitleMenu`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbartitlemenu). That is the menu that is displayed when you tap the down-arrow next to the title. You can put your picker there, and set the title to a string representation of the currently selected enum value.

```
@State var type = LibraryViewType.albums

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        Color.white // dummy view to put a toolbar on
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarTitleMenu {
                    Picker("Picker", selection: $type) {
                        ForEach(LibraryViewType.allCases, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(item.rawValue)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationTitle(type.rawValue)
    }
}
```